# organize SVN repository

Tags: svn, tfs

I am migrating from TFS to SVN. With TFS, we can group projects by departments like --

```
Source Control Server
 |
 |-- Team A
 |   |-- proj A1
 |   |-- proj A2
 |
 |-- Team B
 |   |-- proj B1
 |   |-- proj B2
 |...
```

Is it possible to do the same on SVN?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but it is better to organize projects separate from the teams. When you have a reorganization in your company you would otherwise need to reorganize your repository with it. This is rarely a good idea.

Comment: However, each team has 20-30 projects. One way or the other, I have to come up with a way to organize these. Let more than 100 projects in same level is not idea. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Stan Any grouping based on the content of the projects will do. As long as you keep a disconnect with your organization.  Personally I have about 80 projects directly under trunk. If I need something I do `svn ls ... | findstr "myproject"`. I can understand how it can be annoying when you use TortoiseSvn.

Comment: What if I want each project belongs to a repository, so the revision number won't interleave. Is that possible?

Comment: You can do that, mod_dav_svn supports "SvnParentPath" which allows you to server all the repositories without making extra config. It also dumps the list of repositories if you access the parent path from a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it using folder per team or repository per team whatever you prefer and you can properly adjust security for each as you like. There is section in the documentation to help you decide if you need multiple repositories: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.projects.chooselayout